# How many times in the novels is the narrator not focused on Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

99% of Harry Potter is focused on Harry Potter in his mind. For instance, you never hear the thoughts of Ron or Dumbledore.

Occasionally, such as the first chapter of the first book, you are not seeing the world through Harry's eyes. He is an infant and he is delivered to the Dursley's via Hagrid.

How many scenes throughout the seven novels are not inside Harry's head (or being told through him, such as other people's memories he views, or the Deathly Hallows story)?

**This would be a definitive list of all the chapters in the 7 Harry Potter books which are not from Harry's perspective (ie not open ended).**